# Svelte steam-user script

Tags: svelte, steam, svelte-component, steambot

i am actually trying the steam-user package with svelte and i am trying to show an input for the steam guard code only when `user.on('steamGuard')` asks for it, i don't know if it's actually possible i am new to js and svelte.

the documentation suggests this, i want to get it from a modal component or just an input that is hidden and shows only when it's called.

```
`user.on('steamGuard', function(domain, callback) {
    console.log("Steam Guard code needed from email ending in " + domain);
    var code = getCodeSomehow();
    callback(code);
});`
```

i have tried to get it with the request formData `const body = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData())`

and then

`client.on('steamGuard', (e) => { var code = data.code return(code); });`